# Reorder an array of Chryzode Points to create "Threads" in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Catchy title, huh!

I have a plain JavaScript challenge for you (I gave up!):

Let's take a chryzode with N points (N >= 3) and multiplier M (M >= 2)..

That is, we build a 2- dimensional array with the following values (% is modulo):

```
array_to_order = [[-1,-2], [1, (1*M) % N], [2, (2*M) % N], ...[i, (i*M) % N], ... [N, (N*M) % N]];
```

(The first term, arbitrary and negative, is for later use.)

When  (i*M) % N is 0, take N instead.

For instance, for N=15 and M=2, we have

```
array_to_order = [[-1,-2], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 1], [9, 3], [10, 5], [11, 7], [12, 9], [13, 11], [14, 13], [15, 15]];
```

Next, we clean the array by removing:
● All the [i, i] elements;
(Notice here that because of this step, we could have left out the last element of the original array since it is always [N, N..].)
● The second element of "mirror" sets (for instance,  remove [10, 5] and so on in the array for 15,2.)

The cleaned array for 15, 2 is:

```
array_to_order = [[-1,-2], [1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8], [5, 10], [6, 12], [7, 14], [8, 1], [9, 3], [11, 7], [12, 9], [13, 11], [14, 13]];
```

This much I could manage, and now comes the challenge.

The array has to be reordered so that elements forming "threads" follow each other.

For 15, 2, it gives:

```
array_reordered = [[-1,-2], [1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 8], [8, 1], [3, 6], [6, 12], [12, 9], [9, 3], [5, 10], [7, 14], [14, 13], [13, 11], [11, 7]];
```

What is needed is a function that receive array_to_order as an argument and returns array_reordered as well as another array indicating how many elements are in each consecutive thread. For 15, 2, it will be:

```
 stats = [4, 4, 1, 4];
```

Notice the following (learned from my many failed attempts!):

In 15, 2, you end up with 3 disjointed threads of 4 elements and a" loner" thread.

In some other combinations of N and M, later elements could create "thread branches", such as [2 , 6] in 15, 3 that could connect to [6 , 3].

However, at that point, the elements of the [1 , 3], [3 , 9], [9 , 12], [12 , 6], [6 , 3] thread are no longer available...

I hope that somebody will find the challenge worth the try...

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the arrays directly without filtering and rearranging the pairs.

This approach uses a hash table for seen left values and a counter to visit all values.

```js
var fn = x => (x * m) % n || n,
    n = 15,
    m = 2,
    result = [],
    values = {},
    i = 1;

while (i < n) {
    if (values[i] || fn(i) === i) {
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    let l = i,
        temp = [];

    do {
        values[l] = true;
        let r = fn(l);
        if (l === r) break;
        temp.push([l, r]);
        if (l === fn(r)) values[r] = true;
        l = r;
    } while (!values[l])

    result.push(temp);
    i++;
}

console.log(result.map(({ length }) => length));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am floored by how good some people can be at programming.

I don't know how much time it is going to take me to digest this (I could not believe my eyes when I ran the code and it actually functions!)

One little extra request (before.I am myself able to impement it): I very much would like to have the entries that are of the form [i, i] removed... Can you show me!

Comment: @Jean-PaulBardou, please see edit with the comparison with the reuslt of the function call `fn(i) === i`.

Comment: tx much better, although for  example for 100, 100 the first thread reads 1, 100 / 100, 100

or for 15, 3, the fourth thread reads 5,15 15,15